# How can I customize date and plot them ordered in python's matplotlib?

Tags: date, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataset with a column for Date that looks like this:

```
| Date     | Another column |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1.2019   | row1           |
| 2.2019   | row2           |
| 11.2018  | row3           |
| 8.2021   | row4           |
| 6.2021   | row5           |
```

The `Date` column is interpreted as a `float` dtype but in reality `1.2019` means month 1 - that is, january - of the year 2019. I changed it to `string` type and it worked well, at least it seems so. But I want to plot this data against the total count of something, which is the column 2 of the dataset, but when I plot it:

[image: plot of data against count]

the x-axis is not ordered. Well, why would it be? There is no ordered relationship between the string `1.2019` and `2.2019`: there is no way to know the first is january of 2019 and the second one is february. I thought of using regex, or even mapping `1.2019` to `jan-2019` but the problem persists: strings with no date ordered relationship. I know there is the `datetime` method but I don't know if this would help me.

How can I proceed? it is probably very easy, but I am stucked here!

Comment: Change the `Date` column to an actual datetime (very easy using pandas, for example).

Comment: using the `to_datetime()` method? it is not working, actually, because the format `1.2019` cannot be interpreted as date. It gives me the error:  `ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing`

Comment: @Dimitri you need to convert to string, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71410819/16343464)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to datetime with [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].astype(str), format='%m.%Y')
```

or if you have a pandas version that refuses to convert if the day is missing:

```
pd.to_datetime('1.'+df['Date'].astype(str), format='%d.%m.%Y')
```

output:

```
        Date Another column
0 2019-01-01           row1
1 2019-02-01           row2
2 2018-11-01           row3
3 2021-08-01           row4
4 2021-06-01           row5
```

Comment: Perfect. What I was missing was the `astype(str)` and the `format` argument. It was simply that, thank you very much.

Comment: is there anyway to the output be in the format `2019-01` without the day reference?

Comment: Yes, add `.dt.strftime('%Y-%m')` to the command, but this will give you **text**, so no more alignment for graphs if you do not have continuous intervals ;)

Comment: ok, I see. Thank you veyr much for your answers!